# Error message: Commit errors when creating a new shapefile

Tags: qgis

I want to create a shapefile (ESRI shapefile) layer in QGIS version for 3.6.2 for polygons however I keep getting error messages at first it was:

> Error: could not commit changes to layer error 1 feature(s) not added

I then went onto the table changed id column to Text(string) format as I looked up what the error message meant in the hope that it would work, but now I get another error message that says

> Error: could not commit changes to layer error 1 attribute(s) not added

Does anyone know how to avoid these messages so I can go in and out of edit mode in the shapefile?

Comment: Can you specify your QGIS version? Which kind of geometry? Can you open the log panel in the bottom right corner, the small bubles. Maybe you will have some info in the `OGR` tab

Comment: Im using 3.6.2 version of QGIS. I want to create polygons in this shapefile its the first time I have ever tried to create a polygon shapefile as previously only been vectors and I have never run into this issue before. There doesn't seem to be an OGR tab the only tabs I see are python warning, plugins, general, messages. Hope this helps a bit more

Comment: Can you edit and add these information in the original question, for readability. Thanks

Comment: I had similar error messages in an early version of the QGIS-3 series, on a layer with virtual fields. Does this layer have virtual fields?

Comment: I don't know how would you check this?